# insert prompt() after a click of a button in a form

Tags: javascript, html, prompt

I have a form with three input elements. One of those is a button, the third for precision, and when I click on it, the form will do the GET request. But, before the request I want a prompt to confirm the number of tickets, and here, if I press ok, do the GET request. It's possible? Thanks 
Here there is my HTML code:

```
<FORM NAME="formTicket" target="_blank" ACTION='http://localhost:8080/movies/ticket' METHOD="GET" >
<input id="totalTickets" name="numb" type="text" placeholder="Insert number of ticket" size="5" maxlength="1" style="margin-right:20px" /></input>
<input id="totalTicket" name="id" type="hidden" size="5" maxlength="1" style="margin-right:20px" >
    <script>
        var param = location.search.split('id=')[1];
        document.getElementById('totalTicket').value = param;
    </script>
</input>
<input type="submit" class="dettagliButton" id="stmp" value='Ticket' style="margin-left:2px">   
<script>
        var number = prompt("Please enter the number of tickets", "Insert the number here");
        document.getElementById('totalTickets').value=number;
    </script></input>
</FORM>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript using Confirm to cancel form submission](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12226701/javascript-using-confirm-to-cancel-form-submission)

Comment: yes, thank you soo much!!! now i post the solution

Comment: Not necessary. Just delete your question - it is specifically useful to you and anyone else can look at the other

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution thanks at mplungjan, so I have this:

```
<FORM NAME="formTicket" target="_blank" ACTION='http://localhost:8080/movies/ticket' METHOD="GET" onsubmit="prompter();">
<input id="totalTickets" name="numb" type="text" placeholder="Insert number of ticket" size="5" maxlength="1" style="margin-right:20px" />

</input>
<input id="totalTicket" name="id" type="hidden" size="5" maxlength="1" style="margin-right:20px" >
    <script>
        var param = location.search.split('id=')[1];
        document.getElementById('totalTicket').value = param;
    </script>
</input>
<input type="submit" class="dettagliButton" id="stmp" value='Ticket' style="margin-left:2px">       
    <script>
        function prompter(){                
            var number = prompt("Please enter the number of tickets", "Insert the number here");
            document.getElementById('totalTickets').value=number;
        }
    </script></input>
</FORM>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seeing your solution, I suggest this instead - not sure what you want with the hidden parameter:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Tickets</title>
    <script>
    window.onload=function() {
      var param = location.search.split('id=')[1];
      document.getElementById('totalTicket').value = param;
      document.getElementById('formTicket').onsubmit=function() {
        var tck = document.getElementById("totalTickets").value;
        if (!tck) {
          alert("Please enter number of tickets");
          document.getElementById("totalTickets").focus();
          return false;
        }
        return confirm("You are ordering the following number of tickets:"+tck+", correct?");                 
      }
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="formTicket" target="_blank" ACTION='http://localhost:8080/movies/ticket'>
     <input id="totalTickets" name="numb" type="text" placeholder="Insert number of tickets" size="5" maxlength="1" style="margin-right:20px" />
     <input id="totalTicket" name="id" type="hidden" />
     <input type="submit" class="dettagliButton" id="stmp" value='Ticket' style="margin-left:2px" />       
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks, but i have posted only a part of my code, I have already complete all, i don't want that a function appears during the onload of the page

Comment: What do you mean by "a function appears"?